# Searching for a semantic syntax highlighter in Javascript

Tags: javascript, syntax-highlighting, semantics, html-lists

OK, I know, there are literally dozens of already available syntax highlighters out there. But I want one specifically, that implements line numbers through `<ol/>` lists. And *that* reduces the number of possible candidates to one, [Lighter.js](http://pradador.com/code/lighterjs/). Unfortunately, that is MooTools based, and since I decided some time ago to use jQuery, I don't want to embed yet another library just for syntax highlighting.

The [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/wiki/SyntaxHighlighter) does something similar, but uses tables for the line numbering, and I don't want to hack it, if there is an already available tool, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I finally went with server-side:

PHP: Use GenSHi,

Python: Use Pygments.

Both are easily customizable, and I can cache the results, so there are no jumps on the page compared to an JS solution.

**Edit:** Seems, that my magical unicorn comes to a life: [jQuery Syntax Highlighter](http://github.com/balupton/jquery-syntaxhighlighter)

**Edit 2:** And another one: [snippet](http://steamdev.com/snippet/)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that even my google-fu didn't do the truck to find this unicorn. I presume that you're left with:

- either change your mind about using a separate library for syntax highlighting
- or create this unicorn and make it available for the potential interested people out there

Comment: It shouldn't be a unicorn. `<ol/>`s should be the obvious method to do line numbering (e.g., GeSHi does it server-side), so I hope that there is a syntax highlighter in JS that does it as well and possibly without another dependency.